# Save form data via ajax with no server code

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am looking for a way to save simple form data from a static web page without any server-side code. I've considered something like MongoLab via RESTful interface, but that would require including API credentials client-side and the saved data must be private. Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: what exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I have a web form that collects contact info. I want to save this info into a db (somewhere) without having to set up the server-side code to do it myself.

Comment: So if this DB is not going to be on a server then where is it going to be?

Comment: In the cloud (as via mongolab)...

Comment: I'm not sure MongoLab will work out due to CORS problems, but they might have an option to set up headers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hadn't thought of using a BaaS (back-end-as-a-service) provider like parse or stackmob, but that's the solution. Just hadn't thought of using it for a simple, static web page. I signed up for parse.com and was collecting data within five minutes!

Answer (score 1):

you need to post you form data somewhere, so you must have a server listening for a http form submit, or alternatively use something like socket.io / WebSockets to send all the data to a server. You cannot write to a database from a user browser without contacting some server that will write the information to the database..